# How to render entity reference data in field template?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a **field collection** with adding multiple items. In each item there is an **entity reference field** with multi-selection of contents. I can render entity reference content by **target_id** using `node_load` in an **entity_reference field template**. But it is getting only first value of each item.

How can I render all contents of each item from **field collection**? Is  there another way to fetch?

Comment: any specific reason for using node_load in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below code `template.php`;

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['node']))   {
    switch ($variables['node']->type) {
      case "value":
        $var_abc = $variables['node']->field_abc;

        foreach ($var_abc['und'] as $key => $value) {
          $variables['abc_fields'][] = $value;
        }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Paste the below code to create separate node tpl for that specific content type;

```
<?php
foreach($variables['abc_fields'] as $key => $value) {

  $var_authorvalue = $value['node']->field_author;
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r($var_authorvalue['und'][0]['value']);
  $var_fields = $value['node'];
  print render($var_fields->title)."<br/>";
  print render($var_authorvalue['und'][0]['value'])."<br/>";

}
?>
```

OR

Check [How can I print a field from a referenced entity in my theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70672/how-can-i-print-a-field-from-a-referenced-entity-in-my-theme)?

Comment: Thanks adi for reply! But in my case, i can't create node template, I want to get entity-reference data into my field template.